# Magento 2.1.10 Composer Sample Data Install Issues

Tags: magento-2.1, composer, sample-data

I have Magento 2.2.0 setup with sample data. I am trying to setup Magento 2.1.10 with Sample Data for reference. However, when running:

`php bin/magento sampledata:deploy`

I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/module-bundle-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package magento/module-catalog-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package magento/module-catalog-rule-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package magento/module-cms-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package magento/module-configurable-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 6
    - The requested package magento/module-product-links-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 7
    - The requested package magento/module-customer-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 8
    - The requested package magento/module-downloadable-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 9
    - The requested package magento/module-grouped-product-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 10
    - The requested package magento/module-msrp-sample-data could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  ...

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
There is an error during sample data deployment. Composer file will be reverted.
```

Composer tries to fetch the version `100.1.*` for these modules but can't find it. (For reference it tries and successfully gets version `100.2.*` for Magento 2.2.0.

Any ideas or thoughts on getting the sample data via composer in Magento 2.1.10?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in mangeto 2.2:-

here `/var/www/html/magento2/` is your root project path:-

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures /var/www/html/magento2/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/small.xml
```